# Should Web API server use session id and/or auth-token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api, rest, concurrency

According to @Veraticus's answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197863/web-application-without-sql-query-for-current-user-authentication), Web authentication framework are saving the ID of the current_user in a *session id* in order to quickly and easily retrieve the user from the database (without fetching the user each time with a new query on the database).

This is great because it's exactly what I want to do with my own server (for performance reasons), through its API which I'm writing.

But I wondering about *session id*... I mean, if the server handle sessions, the client have to provide to him a *session id*.

However, I'm also wondering about another thing: in general, Web API are using an *API key* (for instance, https://api-docs.heroku.com/). And using an *API key* and a *session id* may be complicated for the client...

I hope Heroku don't perfom a database query with the received auth-token at each HTTP request. But if they don't, how could they do to authenticate a user without its *session id*?

I'm confused. Thank you a lot for any ideas.

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev: In order to perform only 1 SQL query at the first HTTPS query, and then some other HTTPS queries without SQL ones, how could we implement the mechanism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Session and auth tokens / API keys are very different approaches to authentication and serve different use cases.

**Sessions** are most commonly used in HTML websites for example, where the user authenticates once with the server (typically by presenting a username and a password) and then browses the site without having to re-authenticate themselves at every request. This has requirements on the server, which needs to be able to maintain the session state and store it in memory, as well as the client, which needs to be able to store the session ID (usually in a cookie) and present it at every request.

**Auth tokens / API keys** can be considered as more lightweight in the sense that there is no state to maintain between requests (the server is stateless). Every operation is pretty much atomic and the client has to authenticate themselves at every request (with the token / key). This approach is better suited for programmatic access to a server resources through a "program" rather than a user web browser.

IMO, it doesn't really make sense for a **client** to use both at the same time. If the user is already authenticated with a session, the server already know who is calling it and doesn't need to ask for an extra API key.

OTOH, your **server** Web API could be smart enough to accept both form of authentication from clients.  When called, it could check if the client has already established a session (in which case it knows who is calling it), and if not check if the client is passing some API key / auth token and authenticate the user on the fly.

To answer you last question, since an API protected with a key or a token is stateless, each call needs to be individually authenticated. That means it needs to load information about the client for every request to verify the key. Usually this information is stored in a DB so that could mean a DB hit at every request, unless the server implements some kind of caching to speed things up (which is most likely the case with Heroku).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, @christophe-l. I would like to have a caching system such Heroku in my Sinatra applications.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not very familiar with Sinatra but [memcached](http://memcached.org/) is a really nice language-agnostic caching system that can also [work with Sinatra](http://railsillustrated.com/blazing-fast-sinatra-with-memcached.html).

Comment: How it comes that an auth token is stateless? Does the server environment not need to store the token and save information which user is authenticated with that token?

Comment: @iRaS This answer is now more than 10 years old, but I guess Christophe meant self-contained tokens such as JWTs that are data (header and payload) plus a signature as a proof of integrity/untamperedness (if that is a word ;D). But yes, there are also tokens that require the servers to keep track of them.

Comment: thats this platform... it is not a forum where at some point a topic is just not relevant anymore. yes, with such tokens you could be stateless but it was not mentioned - in fact it was equated with API keys. Also is such a token somehow risky if you are not using a strong algo for the signature - that should at least also be mentioned. TBH at the end it is a much bigger discussion that nobody wants to hear: nothing is stateless or often a security risk (at least an entrypoint for a DOS attack)